# Typescript: constants in an interface

Tags: typescript

How do I place a constant in an Interface in typescript. Like in java it is:

```
interface OlympicMedal {
  static final String GOLD = "Gold";
  static final String SILVER = "Silver";
  static final String BRONZE = "Bronze";
}
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You cannot declare values in an interface.

You can declare values in a module:

```
module OlympicMedal {
    export var GOLD = "Gold";
    export var SILVER = "Silver";
}
```

In an upcoming release of TypeScript, you will be able to use `const`:

```
module OlympicMedal {
    export const GOLD = "Gold";
    export const SILVER = "Silver";
}

OlympicMedal.GOLD = 'Bronze'; // Error
```

Comment: You can now use `tsc --target ES6` to have the below script compile.

Comment: unfortunately this breaks if OlympicMedial is already defined as an interface :( can you please just add consts to interfaces?

Answer (score 11):

Just use the value in the interface in place of the type, see below

```
export interface TypeX {
    "pk": "fixed"
}

let x1 : TypeX = {
    "pk":"fixed" // this is ok
}

let x2 : TypeX = {
    "pk":"something else" // error TS2322: Type '"something else"' is not assignable to type '"fixed"'.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since nobody gave the actual answer of how to do it with an `interface` (to be used in interface/class merging for example).

```
interface Medals {
  GOLD: 'gold';
  SILVER: 'silver';
  BRONZE: 'bronze';
}
```

This will make

```
const a: Medals = { ... }
// type of a.GOLD is the literal 'gold'
```

Although you should consider using an `enum` or `const medals = { ...definition } as const` or even a `class`.

##### Appendix: Objects, Arrays and Classes

Const arrays and const objects can be done like this.

```
const constArray = ['array', 'of', 'emperor', 'Constantine'] as const;
const constObj = { gold: 'GOLD', silver: 'SILVER', bronze: 'BRONZE' } as const;

interface Constants {
  constArray: typeof constArray;
  constObj: typeof constObj;
}

const obj: Constants = {} as any;
const str = obj.constArray[3]; // str has type 'Constantine'
const gold = obj.constObj.gold; // gold has type 'gold'
```

For a class-based approach

```
class Medals {
  static readonly GOLD = 'gold';
  static readonly SILVER = 'silver';
  static readonly BRONZE = 'bronze';
}

// Medals.GOLD has literal type 'gold'
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround for having constants in a interface: define both the module and the interface with the same name.

In the following, the interface declaration will merge with the module, so that OlympicMedal becomes a value, namespace, and type. This might be what you want.

```
module OlympicMedal {
    export const GOLD = "Gold";
    export const SILVER = "Silver";
}

interface OlympicMedal /* extends What_you_need */ {
    myMethod(input: any): any;
}
```

This works with Typescript 2.x

Answer (score 3):

A recommended way to establish constants in an interface, [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2) and is similar to another answer here, is to do:

```
export class Constants {
  public static readonly API_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:6666/api/';
  public static readonly COLORS = {
    GOLD: 'Gold',
    SILVER: 'Silver',
    BRONZE: 'Bronze'
  };
}
```

This is the preferred way to define constants without being hacky, or [disabling settings in the TSLinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202309/why-is-tslintrecommended-not-allowing-modules) (because module and namespace will throw many warnings via the linter).

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
class Foo {
  static readonly FOO="bar"
}

export function foo(): string {
  return Foo.FOO
}
```

You can have private constants as well like this. It seems interfaces can't have static members though.