# call a global constant into service Angular2

Tags: service, interface, angular, constants

In my Angular2 application I use services which call a REST API like this from `http://localhost:22222/app/webresources/entity..`

I want to set part of this URL just one time and call it from the services which I need.
I think I need to create an Interface which has a constant URL, but is it possible to implement this in a service?

Comment: this post should help you.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2

Comment: Thank u , that's exactly what i want  I will try it now

Answer (score 1):

I put something like this in my data-access.service.ts:

```
export const API_URL: string = "http://my.api.com/"
```

It's useful because I can use it in my service methods:

```
getStuff(): Observable<Stuff> {
    return this.http.get(API_URL + `/path/to/stuff/with/${parameters}`)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(this.logError);
```

Or later in a template somewhere:

```
import { API_URL } from '../shared/data-access.service';

@Component({
    template: '<a href="{{api}}/stuff">Link to stuff</a>'
})
export class MyComponent {
    api: string = API_URL;
…
}
```