# Ionic2/Angular2 - Read a custom config file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm working on an ionic2 project and I need to create a new custom JSON config file. I found some tutorials to create one and access it through http.get but I think it's weird to call it through a get request. I want it in the root folder (where all the config JSONs are) and I open/read the file directly.

I don't know if it's possible, or even recommended ? This is why I'm posting here to have some opinions and solutions :)

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Personally I don't like the *read the config.json file by using the http.get* way to handle configuration information, and even though there must be another way to *just include and read* the json file in your code, since we're using Angular2 and Typescript, why not using classes, interfaces and doing it in a more fancy way?

What I'll show you next may seem more complicated than it should at first (although after reading it you will find it very straightforward and easy to understand), but when I started learning Angular2 I saw an example of how they handled *config files* in the [Dependency Injection guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#dependency-injection-tokens) and I followed that in the apps I've worked on to handle config information (like API endpoints, default values, and so on).

According the docs:

> Non-class dependencies
>
> [...]
>
> Applications often define configuration objects with lots of small
>   facts (like the title of the application or the address of a web API
>   endpoint) but these configuration objects aren't always instances of a
>   class.
>
> One solution to choosing a provider token for non-class dependencies
>   is to define and use an OpaqueToken

So you would need to define a config object with the urls and so on, and then an `OpaqueToken` to be able to use it when injecting the object with your configuration.

I included all my configuration in the `app-config.ts` file

```
// Although the ApplicationConfig interface plays no role in dependency injection, 
// it supports typing of the configuration object within the class.
export interface ApplicationConfig {
  appName: string;
  apiEndpoint: string;
}

// Configuration values for our app
export const MY_CONFIG: ApplicationConfig = {
  appName: 'My new App',
  apiEndpoint: 'http://www...'
};

// Create a config token to avoid naming conflicts
export const MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('config');
```

What `OpaqueToken` is may be confusing at first, but it just a string that will avoid naming conflicts when injecting this object. You can find an amazing post about this [here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/05/23/opaque-tokens-in-angular-2.html).

Then, you just need to include it in the page you need it like this:

```
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { Component, OpaqueToken, Injectable, Inject } from "@angular/core";

// Import the config-related things
import { MY_CONFIG_TOKEN, MY_CONFIG, ApplicationConfig } from 'app-config.ts';

@Component({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
  providers: [{ provide: MY_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: MY_CONFIG }]
})
export class HomePage {

  private appName: string;
  private endPoint: string;

  constructor(@Inject(MY_CONFIG_TOKEN) private config: ApplicationConfig) {
    this.appName = config.appName;
    this.endPoint = config.apiEndpoint;
  }
}
```

Please notice how to include it in the `providers` array

```
providers: [{ provide: MY_CONFIG_TOKEN, useValue: MY_CONFIG }]
```

And how to tell the injector how it should obtain the instance of the config object

```
@Inject(MY_CONFIG_TOKEN) config: ApplicationConfig
```

---

### **UPDATE**

`OpaqueToken` has been deprecated since v4.0.0 because it does not support type information, use `InjectionToken<?>` instead.

So instead of these lines:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

// Create a config token to avoid naming conflicts
export const MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('config');
```

Now we should use

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

// Create a config token to avoid naming conflicts
export const MY_CONFIG_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<ApplicationConfig>('config');
```

Comment: Thank you for these clear explanations. I do prefer this approach as well !

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: I do like it a lot but how do I handle environment dependent configuration? Lets say you use a different API endpoint for your production system. I could specify "productionApiEndpoint" in the config and check environment settings within my angular app but this will leak potentially sensitive data to my production application since the "developmentApiEndpoint" is also in the config.

Comment: That's a very good question @tuna. I'm following [this thread](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/issues/762) to see what's going to be implemented by Ionic Team, to figure out a workflow that handles environment dependent configuration

Comment: I've done it that way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2/40287063?noredirect=1#comment72196008_40287063

Comment: OpaqueToken is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks @Celik for pointing that out. I've updated the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

After reading and reading different solutions I ended up using this hacky implementation. Hopefully there will be a nice and native solution available soon:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { environment as devVariables } from './environment.dev';
import { environment as testVariables } from './environment.test';
import { environment as prodVariables } from './environment.prod';

export function environmentFactory() {
  const location = window.location.host;
  switch (location) {
    case 'www.example.org': {
      return prodVariables;
    }
    case 'test.example.org': {
      return testVariables;
    }
    default: {
      return devVariables;
    }
  }
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'configuration',
      useFactory: environmentFactory
    }
  ]
})
export class EnvironmentsModule {}
```

and then where ever needed, e.g.:

```
import { Injectable, Injector, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication';

@Injectable()
export class APIService {

  private http: Http;
  private apiURL: string;
  protected authentication: AuthenticationService;

  constructor(
    public injector: Injector,
    @Inject('configuration') public configuration: any
  ) {
    this.http = injector.get(Http);
    this.authentication = injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    this.apiURL = configuration.apiURL;    
  };

...
```