# Best practice for string String in Ionic 3

Tags: string, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, provider

What is the best practice for storing all app Strings in Ionic 3. Should I created one data provider and store all strings as constants?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App.settings - the Angular-4 way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-4-way)

Comment: Please also take a look at **[this ionic-related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39576991/ionic2-angular2-read-a-custom-config-file/39577841#39577841)**

Comment: @sebaferreras OpaqueToken was deprecated for InjectionToken in Angular 4. I suggest updating that answer :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @suraj. Seems like I had two different answers for the same question... I've updated the link to the comment and retracted my close vote since it was the wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways.But I have chosen very simple approach here.That is, Just create a `static class` as shown below.

**Note:** I extracted below example from my working project.

Constant file:

*Handlers.ts*

```
export class Handlers {
    static BUDGET_PAGE_TOTAL_HANDLER = "budget-page-total-handler";
    static NEW_PROJECT_PAGE_BUDGET_HANDLER = "new-project-page-budget-handler";
    static HOME_PAGE_TRANSACTION_HANDLER = "home-page-transaction-handler";
}
```

Use like this:

*.ts*

```
import { Handlers } from '../../constants/Handlers'; 

eventHandlers() {
  this.events.subscribe(Handlers.HOME_PAGE_TRANSACTION_HANDLER, this.transactionHandler);
  }
```

Comment: Interesting.. Although Angular way is to use [injectiontoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-4-way) and inject in constructor wherever necessary

Comment: Yeah.. There are multiple ways. I have chosen very simple approach here and working fine :) @suraj

Comment: The only difference is that **injecting** the _instance of the class_ (instead of using the static properties from the class directly) will allow you to write unit tests in an easier way (you can easily mock everything). But they should both work properly

Comment: Thank you. Also is there any issue if I use constants without injecting in the constructor?

Comment: There is no problem if you use constants while just importing them. I personally think its much more clearer to read than static properties of a class

Comment: Any reason why you aren't declaring ngx-translate content in your project. Then using the Translation Service/Translate pipe to load the content?    https://ionicframework.com/docs/developer-resources/ng2-translate/

Comment: You can see the difference if you read the `sebaferreras` comment above.

Comment: I don't know how your comment is related to this post? @ErnestoRendon