# Is there a difference between this two ways to Inject a Service in Angular2 / Ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I was looking into "how to use Constants on Angular2" and found [this post with this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287063/1255819) where one have to create a class with an `OpaqueToken`, import it on `app.module` and use it as a provider in the `@NgModule`. In the Page Class or service import it and inject it with `@Injectable()`.

Then I searched on how to create a "factory like in AngularJS" and find out this post about [sharing data between components in Ionic2](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-2-sharing-data-between-pagescomponents/2/), in it you create a simple class without an `OpaqueToken` and import it in `app.components`, register it as `provider` on `@Component` and in the App constructor. Finally import it on the page class and inject it (no need to use `@Inject()`)

Is there a difference between this two? at first glance seams like those both do the exact same thing and I find the second way *easier*.

**Edit**

User *estus* pointed out in a comment, the first one with the `OpaqueToken` will inject a class and the second example inject a class instance. Does this means that with the first example every page will have their own instance of that class ? so 10 pages = 10 instances ? is it not counterproductive (or inefficient) for share static data/constants between them?

Comment: `OpaqueToken` is used in `useValue` providers exclusively. The first example injects a class. The second injects class instance. Considering that you have experience with A1, the things you're asking is already available in the question you've quoted, here http://stackoverflow.com/a/34987036/3731501 .

Comment: Yes but, that question was corrected by the question I posted with the "official correct way". Also the link for that documentation does not exist anymore.

Comment: the number of instances depends on *where* you set as provider..If you set in **ngModule** it is a singleton and if you try to set in **component** it creates an instance for the component.

Comment: Again, OpaqueToken helps to inject a class, to create an instance manually with `new`, constructor args may be service deps or something else. The same thing as `app.value('Class', Class)` in A1. This is for the cases when you need 10 instances. It is up to you if it is  efficient or not. If you misuse this, then yes, it is counterproductive.