# Laravel API with Angular 5 - Access-Control-Allow-Origin Issue

Tags: ajax, angular, laravel, rest, httprequest

I'm using Angular 5 front-end & Laravel 5.6 Backend as Rest API

Now I'm trying to get Access Token using:

```
   const url     = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token' ;
   const body    = JSON.stringify({
                      'client_id'    : '8',
                      'client_secret': 'nMfgx0XrlfvImZK1vqu7PucCaaezDZofJOhTLh4m',
                      'grant_type'   : 'password',
                      'username'     : 'admin',
                      'password'     : '0a09943d507c591ae7269042a57db16ac9a2b971'
                    });

    const httpOptions = {
                          headers: new HttpHeaders({
                            'Accept'      : 'application/json',
                            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
                          }
                          )
                        };

    const res  = this.http.post<any>(url, body, httpOptions)
                          .subscribe(myres => { console.log(myres); }) ;
```

It's working fine on PostMan but With Angular Show this Error:

> login:1 Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8000/oauth/token: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I heard should use somthing called :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')ce
```

Comment: Did you try searching for e.g. *"laravel enable CORS"*?

Comment: yes i did and i found this  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')

Answer (score 5):

you need cors package:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors
```

once installed, go to /config/app.php, add the following to 'providers' array:

```
Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider::class,
```

in /app/Http/Kernel.php add the following:

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
];
```

afterwards run this:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Cors\ServiceProvider"
```

then add your the url that angular serving from in the allowedOrigins in config/cors.php

```
    'supportsCredentials' => true,
    'allowedOrigins' => ["localhost:4200"],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
```

run `php artisan config:clear` and you are good to go

Answer (score 2):

1. Make new Middleware : `php artisan make:middleware addHeadersCors`
2. Put this code inside it (`Http/Middleware/addHeadersCors.php`):

   ```
   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       return $next($request)
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Authorization, X-Requested-With');
   }
   ```
3. Assign the middleware to the Kernel (`Http/Kernel.php`) :

   ```
   protected $middleware = [
       ..
       ...
       \App\Http\Middleware\addHeadersCors::class,
   ];
   ```

Comment: Assuming you found this somewhere, please reference it correctly by providing a link to the source. Otherwise it's plagiarism.

Answer (score 0):

You might or might not need to handle CORS on the server side. You will need CORS if you run your production API backend on a different domain or port than your production front end (which is what I do and would recommend). Then @Hussein's answer is the best one.

But if it's **only for local development**, where your port differs, I would not add another complexity to your laravel application but would instead solve it with a proxy:

In your angular root directory (where your package.json is), create a file proxy.conf.json

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:8000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

then change your package.json to use this proxy:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    // other scripts
}
```

now run the webpack server with `npm start` instead of `ng serve`.

[See this answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46492654/how-run-angular2-front-end-and-symfony3-back-end-api-together-in-development/46898296#46898296)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel:

composer require barryvdh/laravel-cors

Edit  app/Http/Kernel.php- middlewareGroup 's $middlewareGroups content:

```
    'api' => [
        \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        'throttle:60,1',
        'bindings',
    ],
```