# angular 4 application with Visual studio 2017 dot net core. how to access appsetting.json configuration key from typescript file

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am developing  angular  4 application with Visual studio 2017 dot net  core.   want to access appsetting.json  configuration key on typescript file.Also, I am able to access appsetting.json  key on on startup.cs file.But need to access the appsetting.json configuration key from typescript.TS file.

please advise.

Comment: startup.cs  file code....  var config = Configuration.GetSection("Application").Get<Application>();         below object used to acsess  thekey    public class Application
        {
            public string ServiceUrl { get; set; }
        }

Comment: In Visual Studio 2007 Core the files you can use must been in the folder wwwroot (you can create a directory in this folder called "config, e.g., so you can ask about "/config/data.json")

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the angular-cli then you have the enviroment.ts file to store your app settings.

You could load the appsettings.json file in typescript directly, but it does create a dependancy on the dot net core infrastructure.

See [App.settings - the Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way) for the range of options