# Angular storing reference data

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a number of simple lookup tables within my Angular 6 app in the form of:

```
export const Fuel: { id: number, type: string } [] = [
    { "id": 1, "type": "Petrol" },
    { "id": 2, "type": "Diesel" },
    { "id": 3, "type": "Electric" },
    { "id": 4, "type": "Hybrid" }
];
```

I would like to store all of these within a single file allowing these lookup tables to be accessible by all components within a module. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way) post describes using environment files for storing app-settings. Is there a recommended or best practice method for achieving this?

Comment: You can have this tables in normal ts file outside the module and when this tables will be export, then you can use in module.

Comment: The efficient way to do  get these lookups from server using api. so it will have less dependency with client. if you dont want to do that create a modal file put all lookups in it and import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Constant Class with name 'AppSettings' with these properties.

```
export const AppSettings: any = {

   Fuel: [
    { "id": 1, "type": "Petrol" },
    { "id": 2, "type": "Diesel" },
    { "id": 3, "type": "Electric" },
    { "id": 4, "type": "Hybrid" }
   ],

}
```

You can access in any component using.

```
import {AppSettings} from './AppSettings.ts';

console.log(AppSettings.Fuel[0]); // { "id": 1, "type": "Petrol" }
```