# How to get the app settings value from web.config file to angular JS Controller

Tags: c#, angularjs

My AngularJs Code:

```
var Customer = '<%=ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CusID"]%>';
alert(Customer);
```

Web Config Code:

```
<configuration><appSettings><add key='CusID' value='POKA' /></appSettings></configuration>
```

I want to get Web config app settings values from my angular js controller.Can anyone help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: You could use ng-init in your html to initiate a variable in your controller from the markup, instead of from the controller. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 0):

Create a service to read settings ,

```
 using AngularClient.ViewModel;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

    namespace AngularClient.Controllers
    {
        [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ClientAppSettingsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ClientAppSettings _clientAppSettings;

        public ClientAppSettingsController(IOptions<ClientAppSettings> clientAppSettings)
        {
            _clientAppSettings = clientAppSettings.Value;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(_clientAppSettings);
        }
    }
}
```

then call that service to get values .

```
  configClient() {

    // console.log('window.location', window.location);
    // console.log('window.location.href', window.location.href);
    // console.log('window.location.origin', window.location.origin);

    return this.http.get(window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + '/api/ClientAppSettings').map(res => {
        this.clientConfiguration = res.json();
    });
}
```

[angular-configuration-using-asp-net-core-settings](https://damienbod.com/2017/08/13/angular-configuration-using-asp-net-core-settings/)

[app-settings-the-angular-way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793384/2739697)