# Angular 7: build app with external config being excluded from the bundle

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7, ng-build

This is probably a familiar topic [App.settings - the Angular way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way) but tbh, after a day of a researching I couldn't find a satisfying solution, hence I ask the question here.

**Goal** is to build an application once, and deploy many times via configurable config file. This is handy for QA and application support team.

**Problem** is, ng build is internalizing the config file into the final bundle.

My question is actually quite simple, can the goal that I have be achieved using the **angular cli** without using the **environments modules** or **custom config service** or **ejecting from ng cli** (not allowed in A7) ?

I want to have the application **config.js** file in **\src\assets\config\** folder, that acts as a simple module.

**config.js**

```
const appConfig = {
    apiUrl: 'some-api-url'
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = appConfig;
}
```

I'm using this module in my angular components that require access to the apiUrl property, let's say

**app.component.ts**

```
import appConfig from '../assets/config/config'

@Component({
   ...
})

export class AppComponent {
   ...
   constructor() {
      console.log(appConfig.apiUrl);
   }
}
```

Running the build (for prod) will always result in the config.js file content being included in the bundle, which is what I'd like to avoid.

**I want to avoid**

- using the environments files. This is anti-pattern
- using the service that gets the config file. This is relatively ok solution, but let's consider this as a **no-go option** for now
- ng eject (not allowed in A7)

**What I've tried**

- importing **json** instead of the module. still being included in bundle.
- add the config module folder into the **exclude** part of the **tsconfig.app.json**. No matter what I put there, it still gets internalized.

**I know this can be done** (with eject or custom cli build)

Because I've seen a REACT project, that's been ejected from create-react-app cli into webpack. What the build does is:

- uses the CopyWebPackPlugin to copy the config files as they are into the **dest** build
- uses the HtmlWebpackIncludeAssetsPlugin to include the config module files (*.config.js) in the index.html as `<script src=...>` for each config file.
- sets the **externals** array https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Has anyone ever done something I'm trying to achieve? Thanks!

Comment: How is this being built and deployed, Is it a manual or automated process?

Comment: That does not really matter at the moment, once can of course automate it via Jenkins or some CI tools. Let's say it's manual, I need to get the package done.

Comment: since one can't even eject anymore, I've looked into the ngx-build-plus and even though that has the 'externals' property, the build has always bundled the config module into the bundle

Comment: @belzebu did you find the solution yet? I have several environments and would like to create one build and deploy across various environment with the help of configuration

Comment: @MSV sorry mate, I've ended up with my custom angular config service..