# How do I create an app specific configuration for Angular with NX/Nrwl?

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx, nrwl

So I have the following project structure:

```
apps
├── car
└── [...]
libs
├── app-car
├── [...]
└── shared
    ├── config
    └── [...]
```

For every app I want to provide a different config, that can be used in the grouped libs.

```
export interface DefaultAppConfig {
  language: string;
}
```

```
export interface CarAppConfig extends DefaultAppConfig  {
  dealerShipName: string;
}
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793384/8408576) is how I provide the config for every app.

But how can I typecast the config (placed in `shared/config`) that the `CarAppConfig` is used only for the group `app-car` and `DefaultAppConfig` for `shared`?

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little more? I think you're asking how to have strongly-typed configuration per app, but using a config service (to load configuration) which is in `shared`. Is that right?

Comment: @MattTester I haven't thought of the placement yet, but placing it in `shared/config` would be a good option. I also edited the question and added the placement of the service. `libs/shared` is a group of libs. Libs that are used across all apps are placed here. Yes I want a strongly-typed configuration per app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand, IMHO, you should keep `DefaultAppConfig`  in `shared/config` and `CarAppConfig` in `app-car`.

Reason: As the name suggest, shared is *shared by all libs*. So, why should other app have access to an object which is out of its scope.

You can `extend` `DefaultAppConfig` in all apps and use it in its `app-car.module` or something.

> Side note: You can also explore the concept of [Tags](https://nx.dev/l/a/structure/monorepo-tags#tags) to have more control over what can be imported into a lib and what should not.

Please let me know if I get it correctly.