# provide a promise to forRoot()

Tags: angular

I want to use a module that needs to provide a config object to its forRoot(), but I get this config object via an HTTP request,  so it returns a promise (or an Observable)

my-module.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
 imports:[{
   someModule.forRoot({ /* config */})
}]
})

export class MyModule{}
```

I tried to provide this config via useFactory

```
@NgModule({
 imports:[{
   someModule.forRoot({ /* config */})
}],
 providers:[{provide: 'someModuleConfigs', useFactory: ()=>Promise.resolve({x: 1})}]
})

export class MyModule{}
```

this causes an error because `.forRoot()` requires an object with some required properties, but in  this solution, I pass just an empty object

also, I tried to use the token `APP_INITIALIZER` to load this object when the app initializes

but again, I pass an empty object to `.forRoot()` which causes the same error

**The question is:**

how to pass a configs object to `.forRoot()` from a Promise?

Comment: Is it your custom module with `forRoot` case, or it's a third-party? There are two cases how can you achieve the result.

Comment: it is my custom module, but also if you have a solution for the other case it would be thankful of you

Comment: You can't achieve that using the forRoot method. Instead, you could have an exposed service in your library that set the variables in an async way.

Comment: please give me the guide line to acieve your suggestion

Comment: May this thread help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way/62057120