# How to share AppSettings in ASP.NET Core with Angular project

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I have a project created using the VS 2022 ASP.NET Core with Angular template.

Everything about the project itself is good, but I am trying to figure out how to get the Angular app to load the .NET Core's `appsettings.json` to use for config, so it's one shared file for ease of use/deployment.

The file structure of the deployed project looks like

- Main Deployment Folder

  - `api.exe` (and all other framework files)
  - `appsettings.json`
  - `wwwroot` folder

    - `assets` folder
    - `index.html` (and all other Angular files)

Initially I went down the path of creating an Angular service to load config from a file as in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54793384/12899737

However, I then realized that I couldn't point to the `appsettings.json` in the deployment folder above the `wwwroot` as that is not being served in the same way and so it was unavailable.

I could use the `angular.json` build settings to include the appsettings, but that just creates a copy of it at build time and puts you back to essentially having to manage 2 config files.

I am also aware that some examples serve the config settings via an API call, I'm considering that as a last resort option but would prefer to keep it file based if possible.

The main 2 questions I have are:

1. Is there any way to have a service in the Angular app served from the `wwwroot` folder that can access the `appsettings.json` file directly in the parent folder, without that file being served?
2. Is it crazy to consider moving the `appsettings.json` down a folder into the `wwwroot` so the Angular app has access to it, and then editing the `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args)` in the API to include that location for `appsettings.json`?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: As an aside... I'd caution against making the server-side configuration data openly available to client-side code.  There are likely to be values in there that users *shouldn't* see.  (System account passwords, connection strings, external API keys, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `ConfigurationBuilder` class in both your ASP.NET Core and Angular projects to read the `appsettings.json` file from a shared folder. You can find an example of how to do this [in this Stack Overflow answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way/54793384#54793384)

Another possible solution is to create a custom service in your Angular project that makes an HTTP request to your ASP.NET Core project to get the configuration settings from the `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: We decided to not get too complicated and just go with the HTTP request method, as none of the settings we're transferring are sensitive