# How to pass a Lib Config using forRoot() with InjectionToken in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-library, runtime-configuration, injection-tokens

I've been inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193049/app-settings-the-angular-way/62057120#62057120) in order to provide my APP_Config as an injection token, I got this in my `main.ts`

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { APP_CONFIG } from './app/config/AppConfig';


function configListener(this: any) {
  try {
    const configuration = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

    // pass config to bootstrap process using an injection token
    platformBrowserDynamic([
      { provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: configuration }
    ])
      .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
      .catch(err => console.error(err));

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

function configFailed() {
  console.error('Error: retrieving config.json');
}


const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.addEventListener('load', configListener);
request.addEventListener('error', configFailed);
request.open('GET', './assets/app.config.json');
request.send();
```

```
export interface AppConfig {
  clientId: string;
  clientSecret: string;
  ...
}
```

I can use the loaded config from any service in my application

```
  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG) private appConfig: AppConfig) {}
```

But I'm not able to pass the config for the shared Library in my **app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...,
    LibModule.forRoot({
      authConfig: {
        clientId: 'XXXXXXXX',
        dummyClientSecret: 'XXXXXX',
         ...
      }
      
    })
  ],
  providers: [
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How can I provide the config in `forRoot()`from the APP_CONFIG InjectionToken ? is there a relevant solution or I have to update the shared Library module ?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
})
export class LibModule {
  static forRoot(configuration: Config): ModuleWithProviders<LibModule> {
    return {
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [{ provide: AUTH_CONFIGURATION, useValue: configuration }],
    };
  }
}


export const AUTH_CONFIGURATION = new InjectionToken<Config>('AUTH_CONFIGURATION');
```

PS: I am trying to load my app configuration at the **runtime** which allows to reuse the same build artifact for all environments (I got ideas from this [article](https://imran3.medium.com/runtime-configuration-for-angular-c9d9082e1de3))

My issue is already mentioned here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/23279#issuecomment-412108311

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution may be quite simple ! we can provide the AUTH_CONFIGURATION directly from our application as the following

```
const generateAuthConfiguration = (appConfig: AppConfig) => {
   return {
     authConfig: {
        clientId: appConfig.clientId,
        dummyClientSecret: appConfig.clientSecret,
     }
   }
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ...,
    { 
      ngModule: LibModule,
      providers: [
        {
          provide: AUTH_CONFIGURATION,
          useFactory: generateAuthConfiguration,
          deps: [APP_CONFIG]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  providers: [
   
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

That's it !