# How to have mock with Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, mocking

I'm looking for a way to have mock data in a CONST or in a .json file when I'm not working without my backend services or network.

For the moment I use my services :

```
get_clubs(): Observable<Club[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.config.apiEndpoint}clubs`, options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .catch((error: any) => 'doing stuff';
};
```

The `${this.config.apiEndpoint}` is my URL defined in my app.config.ts as a global constant ([found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40287063/2215309))

And I started to create some CONST files (user.mock.ts) :

```
export const CLUBS: Club[] = [
    {
        "_id": "...",
        "name": "..."
    },
    {
        ...
    }
];
```

Sometimes I can't reach my backend and I want to pick data from my CONST or my .json files.

Do you have any clues about that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Observable.of`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) to create an observable from a plain array:

```
import { CLUBS } from "./user.mock";

get_clubs(): Observable <Club[]> {
    // You can probably switch between real call and the mocked call below using a config
    return Observable.of(CLUBS);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the `Observable.of`and the tips. I still have to do a if/else statement to catch if i'm with or without the backend but it help me a lot

Comment: Another tip: if you use something like [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you can mock the responses via Fiddler and you can leave your code as it is.