# Where to save global settings in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular (Type Script) there are many config files. Which is the right one to save a global setting?

For example, when I am calling API from local then my `rootUrl` is `localhost:42000` but when I switch on production it should be `http:www.someting.com`.

I want to save this `rootUrl` in some global place so if I switch on production then I only have to change in this `rootUrl`.

Please suggest where should I save these global settings, same as web.config in Asp.Net.

Comment: angularjs and angular 4 **are not the same framework**.  which are you using?  one is javascript, the other is typescript.

Comment: I am using angular 4

Comment: @UmangPatwa its angular not angular js please change

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global constants in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2)

Comment: i think he using TypeScript one

Comment: If the URL that serves your app is also the URL that serves your API, then  you don't need any rootUrl. Just use http.get('/api/blabla'). Otherwise, Angular CLI has environments for that kind of stuff. But all you need is an exported constant wherever you want, that you import wherever yo need it.

Comment: Do we need to build project two times with prod and development, or is there any other way to change the root URL of API pointed on different server and root url change without building the project.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This answer is similar to @trichetriche, with few more details on the code.

For `development/testing` purpose

environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appUrl: 'localhost:4200'
};
```

For `production`

environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
      production: true,
      appUrl: 'mywebsite.com'
    };
```

Usage

service.ts

```
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

this._http.get(environment.appUrl, requestHeaders(options));
```

Make a note of `production` parameter in all the `environment` files.
I believe you could also create more environments like `environment.unittesting.ts`.

Comment: When i switch on production then i have to change `import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';` to `import { environment } from '../../environments/environment.prod';` ? in each service file ?

Comment: No that would not make any sense. You need not do that. Webpack will automatically recognize production and non production files .

Comment: I am using angular CLI

Comment: That is fine. `ng build` will serve your purpose.

Comment: For more details : http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/

Comment: Do we need to build project two times with prod and development, or is there any other way to change the root URL of API pointed on different server and root url change without building the project.

Answer (score 4):

When I first started using Angular 2, I used a global.ts file where I'd put all my variables, so that I could change it easily.

I've then discovered the environments provided by angular CLI. All you have to do is name a file `environment.prod.ts` (for prod), and use `ng build --prod` when you build it. when you develop, use the `environment.ts` file and both files have to have the same variables.

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I have another way to define global settings. Because if we defined in ts file, if build in production mode it is not easy to find constants to change value.

```
export class SettingService  {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  public getJSON(file): Observable<any> {
      return this.http.get("./assets/configs/" + file + ".json");
  }
  public getSetting(){
      // use setting here
  }
}
```

In app folder, i add folder configs/setting.json

Content in setting.json

```
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:52555"
}
```

In app module add APP_INITIALIZER

```
 {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: (setting: SettingService) => function() {return setting.getSetting()},
      deps: [SettingService],
      multi: true
    }
```

with this way, I can change value in json file easier.

I applied this in project for baseUrl, dateformat, sessiontimeout...

Answer (score -1):

You can use `process.env` with webpack quite easily. E.g.

```
/**
 * This interface makes sure we don't miss adding a property to both `prod` and `test`
 */
interface Config {
  someItem: string;
}

/**
 * We only export a single thing. The config.
 */
export let config: Config;

/**
 * `process.env.NODE_ENV` definition is driven from webpack
 *
 * The whole `else` block will be removed in the emitted JavaScript
 *  for a production build
 */
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  config = {
    someItem: 'prod'
  }
  console.log('Running in prod');
} else {
  config = {
    someItem: 'test'
  }
  console.log('Running in test');
}
```

and you can change `process.env.NODE_ENV` using `webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"' --config ./src/webpack.config.js`

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/build-toggles.html

Comment: This is useless if hes using the angular CLI (which he probably is using)