# Angular 6 - externalizing url

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am trying to externalize the url and proerties in angular 6.

Have a service which invokes 3rd party URL to get data.

weather-component.html -> weather.component.ts -> weather.service.ts

In my weather.service.ts,

```
public getWeather() {
     // Here I have hardoded the URL and the api key.   
}
```

I would like to externalize this so as to make it configurable.

Not sure how to move it to a configurable file and read from there.

Comment: what do you mean externalize or configurable?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Comment: I am not sure if I got the question right, but check this SO post out - https://stackoverflow.com/q/34986922/4794396. In short, you can have a special class with bunch of constants that you may need to access.

Comment: You can have a json config file either on your client or server and GET it. the benefit is that you can change it after build.

Comment: i guess you want to have a service to connect to external URL or make http calls.

Comment: Do you want a public base url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same manish's answer but when we started the project in Angular 2 , this blog had been quite helpful. Over the upgrades over http gateway has changed massively and it was very useful when angular changed the httpclient in 4 .

[https://blog.sstorie.com/adapting-ben-nadels-apigateway-to-pure-typescript](https://blog.sstorie.com/adapting-ben-nadels-apigateway-to-pure-typescript/)

Also if you are looking for a place to put base url etc , I would use the environment ts file in angular-cli
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-application-environments

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to make  generic service

you can have a `baseHttp.service.ts` and `weather.service.ts` will extend the baseHttpservice to make the api calls.

> baseHttp.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export abstract class BaseHttpService {
    private baseUrl: string = Constants.BASEURL;
    protected method: string;
    protected serviceUrl: string;
    protected headers: Headers;

    constructor(private http: Http) {
        this.headers = new Headers();
        this.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        this.headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    }

    call(params: any) {

        let url: string = this.setUrl();

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
        options.url = url;
        options.method = this.method;
        options.body = params;
        return this.http.request(url, options).toPromise()
            .then((response: any) => this.extractData(response))
            .catch((error: any) => this.handleError(error));
    }
    //complete the other functions
}
```

> weather.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class DashboardService extends BaseHttpService {
    constructor(private _http: Http) {
        super(_http);
    }

    getWeatherReport(params:any) {
        this.serviceUrl = 'some-url';
        this.method = "GET";
        return super.call(params);
    }
}
```

so you can inject weather.service.ts and override the values in weather.service.ts and make http calls

so `baseHttp.service.ts` acts as a interceptor, so you can intercept all the Http calls  there.