# save rootscope value in the project

Tags: angularjs, node.js, electron, filepath

I have a task to store a model value in my Electron Angular project . The rootscope model is binding the file path value .

I want to save this path on my project and every time when user will open this app by default it will be present there

`$rootScope.Path = user_path[0];`

I want to save this `$rootScope.Path` and make the data persist on that location everytime.

Any way to achieve this in electron/node.js ?

**EDIT:-**

```
$rootScope.fPath = "C:\\";

    /*Configure FILE path*/
    const {dialog} = require('electron').remote;
    $scope.getFile = function(){
        var file_path = dialog.showOpenDialog({
            properties: ['openDirectory']
        });
        console.log(file_path);

        $rootScope.fPath = file_path[0] + "\\bin";
```

*I want to make this `$rootScope.fPath` path persist whenever I will open my app the previous selected path must be there already. So that I don't have to make further changes.*

Comment: NodeJS: global const variable doesn't satisfy your requirement?

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Sorry not able to catch you

Comment: does this help?... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2

Comment: @AIqbalRaj Nope , I didn't get yet. I am using angularjs 1.x

Comment: Can you share a minimal working example with exactly what you are doing and trying to achieve... that'll help;

Comment: @AIqbalRaj I have added the EDIT section

Answer (score 0):

having a code snippet helps... is this what you're looking for ??

```js
   

      var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        
      app.run(function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.fpath = 'http://someSite/someFile';
      });
      
      app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        
        console.log("fpath:" + $rootScope.fpath);

        $scope.getFile = function(){
          var file_path = dialog.showOpenDialog({
              properties: ['openDirectory']
          });
        }

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
    <p>The fPath as defined globally: <mark>{{fpath}} </mark></p>

    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">  
      <p>The fPath as when accessed in the controller: <mark>{{fpath}}</mark> </p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So if I close my application or redirect to other page , do the declared file path will be there  ?

Comment: this is accessible inside the AngularJS single-page-application... even if you have a router and move around in the application, it should work

Comment: Yes , I am doing this in Node/Electron way. I achieved this by using https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store