# How to define a private constant variable in Angular 2+ components

Tags: angular, constants, angular-components, private-members, class-constants

Do we have something like private static variable in component itself. Not like [Global Constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants-in-angular-2) , But something private to the class (component) itself.

Comment: You mean a private property? something like `private address: string = 'xxxx'`?

Answer (score 4):

You need `private readonly constant = 'constant'`;