# Angular best practice - where store applicaiton settings from API

Tags: angular, data-structures, angular-data

In my application I want to get initial call with some settings for application. These will include forms data (validation rules, dropdowns' options...), maybe some other settings (tbd).

What is best practice of storing this data?

Just object in server? Local storage?....

In AngularJS I remember using rootScope (which was not ideal).

Thanks for advice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Define global constants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986922/define-global-constants)

Comment: Also try using a service . that should also do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two recommended practices,

When you create your angular application with Angular CLI  you always have a folder with environment files:

```
<APP_FOLDER>/src/environments/
                       └──environment.ts
                       └──environment.prod.ts
```

you can create additional target-specific configuration files, such as environment.qa.ts and environment.staging.ts.

and use them in your service (the correct environment file is chosen automatically).

Other way is to add your json files to assets folder and use http get to serve those files.

Comment: The second approach here is useful when having a dockerized frontend configuration: you want your environment splitted from the full bundle so that you can customize it : https://pumpingco.de/blog/environment-variables-angular-docker/