# Why is tslint:recommended not allowing modules?

Tags: typescript, module, tslint

We are using typescript v2.3.2 and TSLint v4.5.1 with VS Code to create a SPA. Codebase is growing and we need to modularize it someway.

I tried to do the modularization using typescript modules but found the following lint error when transpiling the app.

```
[tslint] 'namespace' and 'module' are disallowed (no-namespace)
```

I'm using this configuration for the linter:

```
{
  "extends": "tslint:recommended",
  "rules": {
    "no-var-requires": false,
    "no-console": ["error", false],
    "max-line-length": [false]
  }
}
```

[The recommended rules file](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/configs/recommended.ts) at line 89 shows this rule:

```
"no-namespace": true,
```

I wonder if there is something wrong and what would be the best way to modularize a SPA, following good practices that are not obsolete soon.

Examples of code will be welcomed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Use standard ES6 modules. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

Comment: If you want to use namespaces, which could be appropriate for a large codebase, then turn off the rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [tslint] 'namespace' and 'module' are disallowed (no-namespace)

Because the are not *standard JavaScript syntax*.

## More

- Namespace is a special TypeScript only syntax for a common JS pattern : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/project/namespaces.html
- Do not use namespaces with `outFile` : https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/docs/tips/outFile.html

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-namespace.md states that `[module/namespace] are considered outdated ways to organize TypeScript code. ES2015 module syntax is now preferred (import/export)` but they don't explain why

Comment: also, they don't provide a way for those who needs to keep using "outFile"