# Can you specify a property must hold a certain value in an interface?

Tags: typescript

I am creating an interface in which I need a property to be explicitly set to a value when it's used.

I have seen I can specify multiple possible values for a property

e.g.

```
propertyA: 'x' | 'y' | 'z';
```

Would this work for single value?

So if I did something like:

```
propertyA: 'x'
```

When the interface gets used to define an object somewhere else, would the compiler complain if a different value was attempted to be used.

Is there a way in my example above, I can say this property can only ever hold a value of 'x'?

I came across `type`'s and wondered if this could be a better way for me to achieve this rather than an interface.

Please correct me if I have misunderstood something here.

Comment: Do this match your [requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26471239/typescript-constants-in-an-interface)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`propertyA: 'x' | 'y' | 'z';` uses two typescript advanced type features.

[Union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) which give us the ability to create a new type that can be either one of a given set of types. So `number | string` means something is either `number` or `string`

[String literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) are types that only accept a single value. So `'z'` can be used as a type, with the meaning that something will only ever be that value. Given this you can write:

```
interface Foo {
    x: 'x'
}
let foo: Foo = {
    x: 'x' //ok
}

let bar: Foo = {
    x: 'y' //err
}
```

So yes you can have an interface with a member that is only ever one value. This is usually useful in conjunction with [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign a value to an interface's param. You can only do it in class or module.